Change colour of single word in Revolution Slider
I want to change the colour of the word Power in my revolution slider to #b0d7ff. Any help is appreciated. My site is opuspowerltd.com
I added the following into the slider rev text content box;
Your <span style="color:#b0d7ff !important;">Power</span> <br> Is Safe In Our Hands

Then I added the following into the custom css tab in slider rev;
body span.custom_color_sl{
color: #b0d7ff;
};

In the rev slider editor it shows the word 'Power' in blue, but both front end and preview are showing it in white still.
